# Why are inference rules necessary?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, philosophy

It has been stated, both on this site and elsewhere, that without inference rules, a theory can only prove its own axioms.

I don't understand how, though, and will try to show derivation without inference rules:

Axioms:

1. $P = P$
2. $\neg(P \land \neg P)$
3. Cows are fat

I will denote the axiom *Cows are fat* as $Q$.

Now, through the interplay of 1., 2. and 3., I derive this theorem:

$$[(P = P ) \land (\neg(P \land \neg P) ) \land (\text{ Cows are fat} = Q) ]\implies ( \neg\neg Q = \text{It is not the case that cows are not fat})$$

One could say this is using the following inference rule:

$$\text{Sps.} \\ P = P \\ \neg(P \land \neg P) \\ P \\ \therefore \neg \neg P $$

But if one must call this logical interplay of axioms an inference rule, then one is robbing the axioms of their meaning. If inference rules are  required, then $\neg(P \land \neg P)$ does not mean *something cannot be true and false at the same time*. If it did mean that, it would be sufficient. Since the axiom is not sufficient to prove anything beyond itself, then that means you can assert it, yet the possibility that something is true and false at the same time remains. That robs it of its meaning, because asserting it does not remove the possibility of its negation being true.

If you want to describe and name the ways of interplay between axioms as inference rules, that is fine, but to say they are necessary to prove theorems is like saying that describing/naming the sky is necessary for it to exist.

Comment: The truth/ falseness of propositions not directly what axiomaization is about. To get the truth/false concept, you ened to define an additional function which would assign to the proposition truth values, but I guess here you have implciitly assigned truth values (?? )

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Yes, I thought the property of being true was an essential part of the definition of an axiom.

Comment: You "derivation" is not correct: the rule of Double Negation must be used to derive $\lnot \lnot P$ from $P$.

Comment: And what is " Cows are fat=Q"? The formal statement will be Q.

Comment: Rules are used to derive new statement from already existing ones.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your first and last comments are begging the question. As for your second comment; the proposition "Cows are fat $=Q$" is simply asserting the axiom, and simultaneously denoting it as $Q$. Perhaps that is incorrect syntax but I hoped the message was clear.

Comment: I too was thrown off by that placement of "Cows are fat=Q". In mathematics, "the area is $A=πr^2$" is easy to understand as "the area, denoted by A, equals $πr^2$". But in a more material or object-oriented context, that sentence does sound like we are calling an equality or assignment/definition an area. (Going on a tangent: is a statement like "therefore we have $A⟹B$" merely asserting an implication or also meaning to conclude that B is true?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, you don't need inference rules to show that some statement is a logical consequence of others, because we can use *[semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Semantics)* to do so. And this is some of what you are doing when you talk about the 'interplay' of the statements involved.

But in the context of logic, when we talk about 'proofs' or 'derivations', we typically mean *formal* proofs and derivations, i.e. through the *syntactical* manipulation of formulas. And yes, the inference rules we use to do so can be seen as 'mere' descriptions of logical consequences that are already the case on basis of the semantics, but in the context of a 'proof system' we are almost invariably referring to a syntactical proof, i.e. something that uses inference rules. Indeed, the 'axioms' of a 'theory' are already syntactical objects, so in that sense what you were really doing in your post was a bit of weird mix between syntax and semantics.

In sum, I think you will find it informative to read about the difference between formal semantics and formal proofs.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand where the origin of my problems lie. I thought axioms were a part of semantics, but they aren't (as you said in your answer). I guess since the axioms are composed of semes, that confused me. So, the axioms and inference rules are all just a formalization of logic, which lies in the semantics, but is formalized into mindless syntax in order to remove distractions. Am I onto something?

Comment: @user110391 You got it! :)